# Netflix Windows 8.1 app can't be found on applications list and can't be installed from the Store

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, netflix

I installed Netflix app from Windows Store, and I was using it normally.
Suddenly one day it stopped working, the pinned tile at Start Screen turned blank, if I search the system for "Netflix" it doesn't find anything, if I go through the apps list I can't find it, and if I check the store it says the Netflix app is already installed, so I can't reinstall it.

Does anybody have a clue of what I should do to fix it?

Comment: [It has not been removed.](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/netflix/d8d75bb2-c5cd-44f2-8c26-c1d1ae5b13fa) what is your exact question?  What [methods](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/5278-apps-uninstall-modern-apps-windows-8-a.html) have you determined did not work when trying to uninstall this application?

Comment: I said I can't find it in my app list, but when I go to its page on Windows Store, it won't let me install Netflix app because it says it's already installed.
I never said I couldn't find it on the Store, @Ramhound .

Comment: I suggest you read the other link I provided then respond to that question.